# What "User name" to input in Zapier to make it send a DM to new Slack Users?

Tags: slack, slack-api, zapier

Zapier actually provides an instant once click link to create this Zap but they don't explain what kind of "variable" I should use.

The "To Username" field is required, and in the select form there are only particular user names, no "variables". I just don't understand how to approach this. Should I send the message to SlackBot or do I need to write custom code? They don't explain this.

This is the one-click page for this Zap: https://zapier.com/apps/slack/integrations/slack/9558/send-a-slack-new-member-a-direct-message

Answer (score -1):

The trigger of this zap is Slack’s « New User », meaning the infos of this new user, including the username, will be collected by Zapier.

Then, you will be able to fill the « To Username » field in the Slack’s « Send Direct Message » with the username returned in the trigger step by clicking « Use Custom Value ».

Zapier offers a convenient « Test with step » option at the end of every triggers and actions. It’s recommended to do it every time as you can see what data is collected by Zapier. It’s always very helpful :)